# Why is moist hydrogen made to react with chlorine to give hydrogen chloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, synthesis, covalent-compounds, hydrogen

Moist hydrogen reacts with chlorine in diffused sunlight to give out hydrogen chloride. Why is moist hydrogen used? Why not dry hydrogen?

Comment: The choice of moist rather than dry hydrogen seems to be driven by some external circumstances of which we have no idea. Dry hydrogen would react just as well.

Comment: The reaction is explosive in direct sunlight. Water acts as a catalyst.

Comment: Nice video of UV setting off the reacti0n at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN82GoBG98s

Answer (score -2):

H2O has h ions so it adds more + ions so that the cl- gets reacted faster towards the H+ ions so water is a catalysts or booster
I hope u understnd